# CSS3 3D Animation Disapearing in Safari

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I've built a simple navigation component for my website, which has left and right swinging 'doors.' These work great in all browsers except for Safari, where the 'door' seems to disappear entirely behind its background when your mouse moves from one door to another. Mousing over one door at a time works fine, as long as you wait for the animation to stop before touching the blue door.

Also, one page of my site has a fixed background video, and on that page the animations do not work at all, the entire div disappears as soon as you hover over it.

I've been working on this issue for quite a while and cannot think of a possible reason for this weird behavior. If I implement the animation without putting it in a bootstrap grid, it works, but once the background video is involved it causes the same problem seen in this codepen.

Thanks in advance for any ideas why this is happening!

HTML:

```
<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 greenbackground">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="greenlink doorleft">
          <h1>Left Swing Link</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 bluebackground">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="bluelink doorright">
          <h1>Right Swing Link</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
```

CSS:

```
.greenlink{
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  padding-top:5em;
  padding-bottom:5em;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-left:-15px;
}

.greenbackground{
  background-color: green;
}

.bluelink{
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  padding-top:5em;
  padding-bottom:5em;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin-left:-15px;
}

.bluebackground{
  background-color:blue;
}

.doorleft{
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.doorleft:hover {
   transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
}

.doorright {
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.doorright:hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-30deg);
}
```

Here's the link to a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgBdJp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why, but giving `.col-xs-6` `position: static` solves it (bootstrap gives it `position: relative`). In this case it doesn't affect anything else so should be ok. Clearly it's a Safari issue.

Comment: This fixes part of the problem, but whenever the background video is involved it completely goes haywire. I'm starting to believe that's a separate bug with the background video though, so I'll accept this answer.